# Xamarin Forms Grid - Row height of "*" in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I know that you can set the row height with a "*" in XAML this way:

```
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
 <RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

but the same expression in C# returns an error:

```
new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength("*", GridUnitType.Auto) },
```

So my question is how to set the row height of a grid to a "*" in C#?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var grid = new Grid ();
grid.RowDefinitions.Add (new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add (new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star) });

var stacklayout1 = new StackLayout { HeightRequest = 100, BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
var stacklayout2 = new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.Blue };

Grid.SetRow (stacklayout2, 1);

grid.Children.Add (stacklayout1);
grid.Children.Add (stacklayout2);

MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = grid };
```

[image: Screenshot of the above layout on iOS]

Comment: Thanks, and how can I make the last row to extend to the bottom of the layout no matter what the content of the row is?

Comment: I do have the same question as @IliaStoilov, Did you solve it?

Comment: Just set the GridUnitType of the row to Auto and set the VerticalOptions of the object you place in the grid to FillAndExpand.